# How to specify file path in REST API call to create an object in Oracle Storage Service

Tags: oracle, rest, cloud

I am using Oracle Storage Cloud Service.
I am able to create Container, list all containers and list all objects with in the specific container.
I have to create an object(i.e. file) in the Container. For this REST URL end point will be like -

```
https://<Service URL>/<API Version>/<ServiceName-IdentityDomain>/<ContainerName>/<ObjectName>.
```

Here object destination will be container. But how can I specify "file path (source of the file)" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File path will be used in request body to upload the file content using REST call.

Answer (score 0):

The file parameter must accompany the request.

curl -v -X PUT \
     -H "X-Auth-Token: token" \
     -T file \
     accountURL/containerName/objectName

More documentation at this link on using the REST API to create an object in a container:

https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/storagecs_common/CSSTO/GUID-DB245613-0347-40FA-A733-B54163B592D0.htm#CSSTO3245